# JSON doesn't seem to like '4D '

Tags: json, coldfusion

I'm running into a strange issue in Coldfusion using the serializeJSON and deserializeJSON functions. When I do the following:

```
<cfdump var="#deserializeJSON(serializeJSON('4D '))#">
```

and load the page, I get an error that reads 'JSON parsing failure at character 2:'D' in 4D'. When I change the D so that the input looks something like '4E ' the page loads fine, but when I change the number so that the input reads something like '5D ' I get the same error. I think I may be accidentally entering an escape character but I don't know enough about character encoding to say that with confidence. Does anyone have any idea about why this might happen?

Comment: pls report to https://bugbase.adobe.com/ with a repo case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears you are using ColdFusion 9.x as this issue has been fixed in later versions of ColdFusion.

This same issue has been asked before, please see [Coldfusion JSON serialization inconsistency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660777/coldfusion-json-serialization-inconsistency)

> Any entirely numeric string with trailing D or F followed by
>   whitespace *[..results in an error when deserialized]*.
>
> ```
> JSON parsing failure at character 9:'D' in {"wtf":4D }
> ```
>
> The parser trims and checks if the last character is `D` or `F` (double or
>   float) and strips it. If the remaining characters are numeric, no
>   quotes are added. If you don't have trailing whitespace, it works
>   perfectly. The specific combo of number, `D|F` and spaces trips it up.

Comment: Awesome thanks. I read that thread before, but didn't scroll down far enough to see my exact question being asked. Have a good day!